# Accessing Nested JSON [AWS Metadata] with Python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services

I'm using Lambda to run through my AWS account, returning a list of all instances. I need to be able to print out **all** of the 'VolumeId' values, but I can't work out how to access them as they are nested. I am able to print out the **first** VolumeId for each instance, however, some of the instances have several volumes, and some only have one. I think I know why I get these results, but I can't work out what to do to get all of them back.

Here's a snippet of what the JSON for one instance looks like:

```
{  
'Groups':[],
'Instances':[  
  {  
     'AmiLaunchIndex':0,
     'ImageId':'ami-0',
     'InstanceId':'i-0123',
     'InstanceType':'big',
     'KeyName':'nonprod',
     'LaunchTime':'date',
     'Monitoring':{  
        'State':'disabled'
     },
     'Placement':{  
        'AvailabilityZone':'world',
        'GroupName':'',
        'Tenancy':'default'
     },
     'PrivateDnsName':'secret',
     'PrivateIpAddress':'1.2.3.4',
     'ProductCodes':[  

     ],
     'PublicDnsName':'',
     'State':{  
        'Code':80,
        'Name':'stopped'
     },
     'StateTransitionReason':'User initiated',
     'SubnetId':'subnet-1',
     'VpcId':'vpc-1',
     'Architecture':'yes',            
     'BlockDeviceMappings':[  
        {  
           'DeviceName':'/sda',
           'Ebs':{  
              'AttachTime':'date',
              'DeleteOnTermination':True,
              'Status':'attached',
              'VolumeId':'vol-1'
           }
        },
        {  
           'DeviceName':'/sdb',
           'Ebs':{    
              'AttachTime':'date'),
              'DeleteOnTermination':False,
              'Status':'attached',
              'VolumeId':'vol-2'
           }
        }
     ],
```

This is what I'm doing to get the first VolumeId:

```
ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2 = ec2client.describe_instances()
for reservation in ec2["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        instanceid = instance["InstanceId"]

        volumes = instance["BlockDeviceMappings"][0]["Ebs"]["VolumeId"]
        print("The associated volume IDs for this instance are: ",(volumes))
```

I think the reason that I'm getting just the first ID is because I'm referencing the first element within "BlockDeviceMappings", but I can't work out how to get the other ones. If I try it without specifying the [0], I get the `list indices must be integers or slices, not str` error. I tried to use a dictionary instead of a list too, but felt like I was barking up the wrong tree with that one. Any suggestions/help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible answer, not particularly pythonic

...

```
id_list = []
volumes_data = instance["BlockDeviceMappings"]
for element in volumes_data:
    id_list.append(element["Ebs"]["VolumeId"])
```

Or else use json.loads and then iterate though json using .get syntax like the [final answer in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385803/aws-lambda-function-is-misinterpreting-event-dictionary-in-python/48391462#48391462)

Comment: Perfect, that's all I needed. I did try doing it with json.load, json.loads, & json.dumps but struggled to do what I needed. Kept getting that same `list indices` error. Thanks for the solution!